How can I fix transparent lines in my scaled images (Javax.swing)?
I am trying to make a small games with a native resolution of 320x180, then scale it up for a bigger window. but I'm getting transparent lines in my sprites.
right now I'm drawing to a BufferedImage then scaling it up with AffineTransformOp. this work well, but there are some transparent lines in my sprite that randomly appear then quickly disappear. below is my code.
public class Window extends JFrame {
    private int width;
    private int height;
    public Window(String name) {
        this.width = 1280;
        this.height = 720;
        this.setTitle(name);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(width, height);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
public class run {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        GamePanel game = new GamePanel();
    }

}
public class GamePanel extends JPanel{
    private static final int HEIGHT = 180;
    private static final int WIDTH = 320;
    private BufferedImage buffer = new BufferedImage(320, 180, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    private BufferedImage scaledImage = new BufferedImage(1280, 720, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    AffineTransformOp scaleOp;
    private BufferedImage spriteMap;
    private Image sprite;
    private Window frame = new Window("Game");
    public GamePanel() throws IOException {
        frame.add(this);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        at.scale(4.0, 4.0);
        scaleOp = new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);
        spriteMap = ImageIO.read(new File("res/image.png"));;
        Game();
    }
    public void Game() {
        while(true) {
            Draw();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public void Draw() {
        Graphics g = buffer.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        sprite = spriteMap.getSubimage(0, 8, 16, 16);
        g.drawImage(sprite, 50, 50, null);
        this.repaint();
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (buffer != null && scaleOp != null) {
            scaledImage = scaleOp.filter(buffer, scaledImage);
            g.drawImage(scaledImage, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }

}


You don't.  You create your images as large as necessary and scale them smaller.

@GilbertLeBlanc I choose to make my game with a native resolution of 320x180 because it and 640X360 are the most common resolutions for pixel are games, since they scale in whole numbers to 1080p 2k and 4k. I get why its normally better to scale down images, but scaling up pixel art works really well. is there some other reason why its not a good idea to scale up images in Jswing?

Your code is hard to read because of your naming. GamePanel should not own Window (not a good name - there's already such a class in the JRE) - it should be the other way around if anything. Your infinite loop is wrong as drawing will probably be occurring on the wrong thread, i.e. not the EDT. Why are you doing it anyway - there doesn't seem to be any animation occurring? Better to load files/images as resources

For your information, according to generally accepted conventions, in Java, method names begin with a lowercase letter. Also, the first line in the body of overridden paintComponent method is usually super.paintComponent(g)

Perhaps you can [edit] your question and post an animated GIF that demonstrates the behavior you are describing? Then, when I copy and run your code, I can be sure that it correctly reproduces your problem. Of-course, you would also need to post a [mcve] in order for me to do that.

Rather than calling method sleep, you should use a Swing timer.

I’m not sure if this is the cause, but… drawing every 3 milliseconds seems pretty over the top.  That’s 333 frames per second!  Why not try 16 milliseconds, which will result in roughly 60 frames per second?

@Abra this code does produce the described issue on my machine, I choose to not include the animation section of my code to make this a minimal reproducible example. is there some reason why this code doesn't qualify as a minimal reproducible example?

is there some reason why this code doesn't qualify as a minimal reproducible example The fact that you've removed the animation (the 'high bar' problem area) would be a very good reason

@g00se the code I have left out just updates the position of the image when the user is pressing a keyboard button. I don't see how this part of the code is relevant, when its not what's causing the issue.

Because the code in your question does not follow Java naming conventions I misread it and didn't realize that run is the name of a class that contains a main method. However, you claim to be having a problem with a background image but you have not included a link to that image so I still can't reproduce your problem.

I don't see how this part of the code is relevant, when its not what's causing the issue. I'm glad you're so much more on top of this issue than I am. I therefore am mystified why you asked a question at all since you're so certain of the problem's causes...

You've also wasted time by removing the key part of the code. If there's actually an animation going on, you need to use a Swing Timer
